# Cannot get SASS to output .css file in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: ruby, netbeans, sass

I'm trying to learn to use SASS to expand my web development skills but I've run into a problem. I'm running Windows 7 , I have installed both Ruby193 and SASS gem and I'm using Netbeans 8.0 as my IDE.

My system path points to `C:\Ruby193\bin` and I can type `ruby -v` from my command prompt without error, so I believe that is set up correctly.

Under `CSS Preprocessors` in project properties I have input set to `/scss` and output set to `/css`. In Configure Executables I have SASS path set to `C:\Ruby193\bin\sass.bat`. From what I have read, this is correct.

I've also got a simple project set up with two directories `css` and `scss` as well as an `index.html` with test text and a link to `css/style.css` in the header. In my `scss` directory I have `style.scss` with some test code. My `css` directory is empty. It is my understanding that when I compile SASS should generate a `css/style.css` from `style.scss`, however it does not.

Both [Netbeans - installing SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660942/netbeans-installing-sass) and [Does Netbeans generate a separate CSS file when saving a SASS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359676/does-netbeans-generate-a-separate-css-file-when-saving-a-sass-file) have the same problem I do, but neither solution seems to work for me. Could anyone offer me some help? I've also attached an image of my settings.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydwKJ.png

Comment: I hope this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921437/css-pre-processors-in-netbeans?rq=1 will provide the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, That worked for me! I didn't realize I needed to have anything in the compiler options. I entered `--style compressed and got the output I was looking for.

Comment: Editing the bat file helped me get NetBeans to compile SCSS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887849/470749

Answer (score 2):

1) create css/styles.css.
2) type "--style compact" and check "Compile Sass files on save" in the CSS compact.