# My netbeans IDE Scss compile not properly.

Tags: css, netbeans, sass

Netbeans 8.1:  I am trying to compile My scss file in netbeans. But netbeans show this error message    .[image]

My computer install ruby and sass. What means this error I don't Understand. Here include Environment variables path

[image]

Finaly I write code in scss file but not compile this code. And not conver to css file. Plz help.. Advance Thanks for every All
.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SASS with Netbeans 8.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965982/how-to-use-sass-with-netbeans-8-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

You need t set the path to SASS not only in PATH variable but also in Netbeans, to do so go to:

Netbeans -> Tools -> Options:
  Select the HTML/JS tab -> Sass Path: fill it with the path to SASS.

Hope it Helps

Comment: I can try this but same problem.

Comment: Try looking at this answer in [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965982/how-to-use-sass-with-netbeans-8-0-1)