# Netbeans 8.1 Sass Syntax Highlighting

Tags: sass, netbeans-8

Iam using Netbeans 8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. Iam working with *.sass files and I had to change the syntax hoghlighting to plaintext because Netbeans does not seem to support sass, just scss works. Is that true? Is there still no syntax highlighting for sass? I found comments, that they wanted to introduce it in 7.4

Answer (score 1):

Sass syntax should work on netbeans, just as scss syntax does too. I googled this and found another post:

[How to use SASS with Netbeans 8.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965982/how-to-use-sass-with-netbeans-8-0-1)

hope that helps!

Comment: thats only about the compiling, that works (however, Iam doing it currently within symfony), but they dont say anything about the syntax highlighting. When I mark *.sass for *.scss highlighting in netbeans its still wrong, of course because they have different syntaxes

Comment: Interesting that they wouldnt have a plugin for that then.