# Netbeans IDE: syntax highlight and validation for .sass extension

Tags: netbeans, sass

The Netbeans IDE supports SASS preprocessor, however the `.scss` extension only. I want to add syntax highlight and syntax validation for `.sass` extension. Where I should start from?

Comment: Take a look at the responses to this SO question: [How to use SASS with Netbeans 8.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965982/how-to-use-sass-with-netbeans-8-0-1) . Does that help?

Comment: @skomisa, I am sorry, this question has not the relationship with mine. It was asked: "how to compile sass (.scss extention) to css in netbeans?". I asked "how to add highlight and validation for .sass extension?". Really there is no way but to code this support by own.